# Android Studio installation not working

Tags: android

I have downloaded the studio but having problem in downloading the components while starting the android studio. The error shows "The following SDK component was not installed: Android Support Repository".
please help me.
It is also showing this error when I tried open " Start a new android studio project " as--- Your android SDK is missing , out of date or is missing template.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hzzVL.png)
[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6x64.png)

Comment: Install Android SDK and set path of sdk folder if required.

Comment: uninstall studio along with sdk, agin install studio has latest sdk will ask you how would you like to add sdk

Comment: still not working.

Comment: please check above pics for to know exact error

Comment: uninstalled and installed several times

Answer (score 0):

Go to Android SDK manager: Tools > Android > SDK Manager
There you can install the required packages

Comment: as i said i am unable to open my android studio i cant see above directories.please check attached photos to see exact error.please help